# Number of palindromes in character strings

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to gather a list of 6 letter palindromes and the number of times they occur using Postgres 9.3.5.

This is the query I've tried:

```
SELECT word, count(*)
FROM ( SELECT regexp_split_to_table(read_sequence, '([ATCG])([ATCG])([ATCG])(\3)(\2)(\1)') as word
       FROM reads ) t
GROUP BY word;
```

However this brings up results that a) aren't palindromic and b) greater or less than 6 letters long.

```
\d reads
Table "public.reads"
Column        |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------------+---------+-----------
read_header   | text    | not null
read_sequence | text    | 
option        | text    | 
quality_score | text    | 
pair_end      | text    | not null
species_id    | integer | 

Indexes:
"reads_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (read_header, pair_end)
```

`read_sequence` contains DNA sequences, `'ATGCTGATGCGGCGTAGCTGGATCGA'` for example.

I'd like to see the number of palindromes in each sequence so the example would contain 1 another sequence could have 4 another 3 and so on.

Comment: Please define table `reads` and your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter What do you mean by define table reads, what do you need to know? and i'm using 9.3.5

Comment: What you get with `\d reads` in psql, the table definiton. Some sample values and the desired result would be helpful, too. Update the question, don't put essential information in comments, please.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Added table def.

Comment: Can there be other characters than `ATCG` in `read_sequence`?

Comment: Technically yes (an N) however I've been ignoring that when looking through palindromes. (Due to there being very low occurrence) @ErwinBrandstetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count per row:

```
SELECT read_header, pair_end, substr(read_sequence, i, 6) AS word, count(*) AS ct
FROM   reads r
     , generate_series(1, length(r.read_sequence) - 5 ) i
WHERE  substr(read_sequence, i, 6) ~ '([ATCG])([ATCG])([ATCG])\3\2\1'
GROUP  BY 1,2,3
ORDER  BY 1,2,3,4 DESC;
```

Count per `read_header` and palindrome:

```
SELECT read_header, substr(read_sequence, i, 6) AS word, count(*) AS ct
FROM
...
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2,3 DESC;
```

Count per `read_header`:

```
SELECT read_header, count(*) AS ct
FROM
...
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1,2 DESC;
```

Count per palindrome:

```
SELECT substr(read_sequence, i, 6) AS word, count(*) AS ct
FROM
...
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1,2 DESC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/75e98/7)

#### Explain

A [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) could start at any position 5 characters shy of the end to allow a length of 6. And palindromes can **overlap**. So:

1. Generate a list of possible starting positions with `generate_series()` in a `LATERAL` join, and based on this all possible 6-character strings.
2. Test for palindrome with regular expression with back references, similar to what you had, but `regexp_split_to_table()` is not the right function here. Use a regular expression match (**`~`**).
3. Aggregate, depending on what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for query and explanation, I've been trying to group it differently (in addition to what you've done) but can't seem to get it. Im trying to accomplish this as well http://pastebin.com/SU43LWd4

Comment: @lenhun: I added a variant for that.

Comment: I still shows the the separate palindromes instead of the total for that specific read header.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @lenhun: Already added another variant. You should have made clear what you want exactly in the question.